# How to access MERN application deployed to alibaba cloud in the browser

Tags: reactjs, express, nginx, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have deployed my MERN application to Alibaba ECS instance. Is there any way to access it in the browser, just like AWS public DNS? In AWS you use the public DNS to access your deployed application. I am not sure what to use to achieve the same. Below is the NGINX config present in the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: nginx]

Surprisingly, I was able to hit the APIs without any issue. you can check the pm2 logs below

[image: pm2]

I am new to cloud deployment. If I have missed anything or if you need more information please let me know. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/deploying-node-js-apps-for-production-on-alibaba-cloud_594639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the problem. In ECS I didn't set up the security group for HTTP(port 80). When I added the security group and tweaked the NGINX configuration a bit, it worked like a charm. Marking my own answer as acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find solution on this two articles on Alibaba Cloud documentation for that problem, if I understood your question correctly:

1. IP addresses of ECS instances within VPCs: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25434.htm
2. Connect to a Linux instance by using a username and password: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25434.htm

Hope this would help